# Can't stop rails server with CTRL-C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Rails. I start the WEBrick Server from scripts/server (via ./scripts/server from the directory created by rails) on Debian. The Server starts and is reachable, but if I press CTRL + C then appears

```
ERROR SystemExit: exit
    [rails dir]/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:106:in `exit'
```

and the Server won't stop. What goes wrong?

Comment: Are you on OSX? If so, make sure you really are using Ctrl + C, not CMD + C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any latecomers, [Rails 2.3.8 doesn't like Rack 1.2.1](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/35)

Add `gem 'rack', '1.1.0'` to your gemfile, run `bundle update rack` and your server should exit correctly.

Answer (score 5):

*nix

First step, lookup the process ID (PID) of `rails server`; you'll need the port it's running on.

Second step, manually kill the process using the PID obtained in step one.

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:<PORT> # e.g. 3000

kill -9 <PID> # e.g. 14319
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the process with `ps aux` in your terminal.

Then, `kill -9` it.